# C# LINQ filter the List of tuple with given List

Tags: c#, linq, tuples

Here is `pariList`(it's `List of Tuple`)

```
 List<Tuple<dynamic, dynamic>> PairList = new List<Tuple<dynamic, dynamic>> = 
 {({ Symbol = a, Close = 1.0, Date = 2/1/2016, Vol = 0 }, { Symbol = b, Close = 1.6, Date = 2/1/2016, Vol = 0 })}   
 {({ Symbol = a, Close = 1.0, Date = 2/1/2016, Vol = 0 }, { Symbol = c, Close = 2.0, Date = 2/1/2016 , Vol = 0 })}  
 {({ Symbol = b, Close = 1.6, Date = 2/1/2016, Vol = 0 }, { Symbol = c, Close = 2.0, Date = 2/1/2016, Vol = 0 })}   
 {({ Symbol = a, Close = 1.1, Date = 2/2/2016, Vol = 0 }, { Symbol = b, Close = 1.2, Date = 2/2/2016, Vol = 0 })}
 {({ Symbol = a, Close = 1.1, Date = 2/2/2016, Vol = 0 }, { Symbol = c, Close = 2.1, Date = 2/2/2016, Vol = 0 })}   
 {({ Symbol = b, Close = 1.2, Date = 2/2/2016, Vol = 0 }, { Symbol = c, Close = 2.1, Date = 2/2/2016, Vol = 0 })}   
 {({ Symbol = a, Close = 1.4, Date = 2/3/2016, Vol = 0 }, { Symbol = b, Close = 1.4, Date = 2/3/2016, Vol = 0 })}   
 {({ Symbol = a, Close = 1.4, Date = 2/3/2016, Vol = 0 }, { Symbol = c, Close = 1.4, Date = 2/3/2016, Vol = 0 })}   
 {({ Symbol = b, Close = 1.4, Date = 2/3/2016, Vol = 0 }, { Symbol = c, Close = 1.4, Date = 2/3/2016, Vol = 0 })}   
 {({ Symbol = a, Close = 1.7, Date = 2/4/2016, Vol = 0.214285714285714 }, { Symbol = b, Close = 1.8, Date = 2/4/2016, Vol = 0.218217890235992 })}
 {({ Symbol = a, Close = 1.7, Date = 2/4/2016, Vol = 0.214285714285714 }, { Symbol = c, Close = 2.7, Date = 2/4/2016, Vol = 0.464743364189122 })}
 {({ Symbol = b, Close = 1.8, Date = 2/4/2016, Vol = 0.218217890235992 }, { Symbol = c, Close = 2.7, Date = 2/4/2016, Vol = 0.464743364189122 })}
 {({ Symbol = a, Close = 1.8, Date = 2/5/2016, Vol = 0.122450941145067 }, { Symbol = b, Close = 1.2, Date = 2/5/2016, Vol = 0.169725025739105 })}
 {({ Symbol = a, Close = 1.8, Date = 2/5/2016, Vol = 0.122450941145067 }, { Symbol = c, Close = 1.2, Date = 2/5/2016, Vol = 0.301649178342484 })}
 {({ Symbol = b, Close = 1.2, Date = 2/5/2016, Vol = 0.169725025739105 }, { Symbol = c, Close = 1.2, Date = 2/5/2016, Vol = 0.301649178342484 })}
  ......
  ......
```

And now, I select some pairs at a special date

```
var wantedCombinations = pairList
                        .Where(pair => pair.Item1.Date == Beginday)
                        .Select(pair => new { Item = pair, Volspread = Math.Abs(pair.Item1.Vol - pair.Item2.Vol) })
                        .OrderBy(o => o.Volspread)
                        .Take(FirstSelect)
                        .Select(item =>item.Item)
                        .ToList();
```

Then how to make the 'pairList' only left those selected pairs in `wantedCombinations` every date. e.g

select `{a, b}, {a, c}`, then `pairList` become

```
 {({ Symbol = a, Close = 1.0, Date = 2/1/2016, Vol = 0 }, { Symbol = b, Close = 1.6, Date = 2/1/2016, Vol = 0 })}   
 {({ Symbol = a, Close = 1.0, Date = 2/1/2016, Vol = 0 }, { Symbol = c, Close = 2.0, Date = 2/1/2016 , Vol = 0 })}  
 {({ Symbol = a, Close = 1.1, Date = 2/2/2016, Vol = 0 }, { Symbol = b, Close = 1.2, Date = 2/2/2016, Vol = 0 })}
 {({ Symbol = a, Close = 1.1, Date = 2/2/2016, Vol = 0 }, { Symbol = c, Close = 2.1, Date = 2/2/2016, Vol = 0 })}        
 {({ Symbol = a, Close = 1.4, Date = 2/3/2016, Vol = 0 }, { Symbol = b, Close = 1.4, Date = 2/3/2016, Vol = 0 })}   
 {({ Symbol = a, Close = 1.4, Date = 2/3/2016, Vol = 0 }, { Symbol = c, Close = 1.4, Date = 2/3/2016, Vol = 0 })}   
 {({ Symbol = a, Close = 1.7, Date = 2/4/2016, Vol = 0.214285714285714 }, { Symbol = b, Close = 1.8, Date = 2/4/2016, Vol = 0.218217890235992 })}
 {({ Symbol = a, Close = 1.7, Date = 2/4/2016, Vol = 0.214285714285714 }, { Symbol = c, Close = 2.7, Date = 2/4/2016, Vol = 0.464743364189122 })}
 {({ Symbol = a, Close = 1.8, Date = 2/5/2016, Vol = 0.122450941145067 }, { Symbol = b, Close = 1.2, Date = 2/5/2016, Vol = 0.169725025739105 })}
 {({ Symbol = a, Close = 1.8, Date = 2/5/2016, Vol = 0.122450941145067 }, { Symbol = c, Close = 1.2, Date = 2/5/2016, Vol = 0.301649178342484 })}
  ......
  ......
```

And it is   better to achieve those two steps in one Linq query?

Comment: @ Gilad Green for example, I have obtain some pair at `2/3/2016` `({a,2/3/2016}, {c,2/3/2016}),  ({a,2/3/2016}, {b,2/3/2016})`, then I want to the `pairList` only left the pair of symbol `{a,c}, {a,b}` for every day as I list in the third code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much talk in the chat this is the answer:

```
var wantedCombinations = pairList.Where(pair => pair.Item1.Date == Beginday)
                                 .Select(pair => new { Item = pair,  Volspread = Math.Abs(pair.Item1.Vol - pair.Item2.Vol) })
                                 .OrderBy(o => o.Volspread)
                                 .Take(FirstSelect)
                                 .Select(item =>item.Item);

pairList = pairList.Where(pair => 
                        wantedCompinations.Any(wc => wc.Item1.Symbol == pair.Item1.Symbol &&
                                                     wc.Item2.Symbol == pair.Item2.Symbol)).ToList();
```

---

In order to keep only pairs that have the symbols in Item1 and Item2 like you described add to the `Where` also a check that the current `pair` is in the options list:

```
var wantedCombinations = new List<dynamic>
{
    new { Symbol1 = "a", Symbol2 = "b" },
    new { Symbol1 = "a", Symbol2 = "c" }
};

var result = pairList.Where(pair => pair.Item1.Date == Beginday &&
                                    wantedCombinations.Any(item => item.Symbol1 == pair.Item1.Symbol &&
                                                      item.Symbol2 == pair.Item2.Symbol))
                     .Select(pair => new { Item = pair, Volspread = Math.Abs(pair.Item1.Vol - pair.Item2.Vol) })
                     .OrderBy(o => o.Volspread)
                     .Take(FirstSelect)
                     .Select(item =>item.Item)
                     .ToList();
```

Another way can be to join the two lists:

```
var wantedCombinations = new List<dynamic>
{
    new { Symbol1 = "a", Symbol2 = "b" },
    new { Symbol1 = "a", Symbol2 = "c" }
};

var result = (from pair in pairList
             where pait.Item1.Date.Equals(Beginday)
             join c in wantedCombinations on new { pair.Item1.Symbol, pair.Item2.Symbol } equls new { c.Symbol1, c.Symbol2 }
             orderby Math.Abs(pair.Item1.Vol - pair.Item2.Vol)
             select pair).Take(FirstSelect);
```

*In anycase if you decide going to the query syntax rather than the method syntax (doesn't matter if you prefer the `.Any` or `join` options) you can then `orderby` without having to add that extra `Select`*

Comment: is it possible put them together? Actually `wantedCombinations`  obtained from `pairList` as showed in second code. That means I first select `wantedCombinations` then filter the `pairList`.

Comment: That means I first select `wantedCombinations` then filter the `pairList`, it isn't like the later part of your solution showed above.

Comment: Sorry, from `pairList`, the second code shows obtaining the `wantedCombinations`  from `pairList`.

Comment: @ Gilad Green I have changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121146/discussion-between-gilad-green-and-user6703592).